# It seems my code for my cs50 problem is close to being correct but I can't figure it out

Tags: python

Can someone help me with my code? Im new to python and currently doing the cs50 Python course, and I'm kind of stuck in problem-set 3.

Problem Description:

> In a file called outdated.py, implement a program that prompts the user for a date, anno Domini, in month-day-year order, formatted like 9/8/1636 or September 8, 1636, wherein the month in the latter might be any of the values in the list below. Then output that same date in YYYY-MM-DD format. If the user’s input is not a valid date in either format, prompt the user again. Assume that every month has no more than 31 days; no need to validate whether a month has 28, 29, 30, or 31 days.

This is my code so far:

```
months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
]

def get_date():
    while True:
        date = input("Date: ").title().strip()
        try:
            month, day, year = date.replace("/", " ").replace(",", " ").split()

            if month in months and 1 <= int(day) <= 31:
                month_number = months.index(month) + 1
                print(year, str(month_number).zfill(2), day.zfill(2), sep="-")
                break

            if 1 <= int(month) <= 12 and 1 <= int(day) <= 31:
                print(year, month.zfill(2), day.zfill(2), sep="-")
                break

        except ValueError:
            pass

get_date()
```

I know I could just watch a YouTube video and copy their response, but I wanted to try to make my own work instead. Hope someone can help.

This is the feedback I get when testing my code:

```
:) outdated.py exists
:) input of 9/8/1636 outputs 1636-09-08
:) input of September 8, 1636 outputs 1636-09-08
:) input of 10/9/1701 outputs 1701-10-09
:) input of October 9, 1701 outputs 1701-10-09
:) input of " 9/8/1636 " outputs 1636-09-08
:) input of 23/6/1912 results in reprompt
:) input of 10 December, 1815 results in reprompt
:( input of October/9/1701 results in reprompt
    expected program to reject input, but it did not
:) input of 1/50/2000 results in reprompt
:) input of December 80, 1980 results in reprompt
:( input of September 8 1636 results in reprompt
    expected program to reject input, but it did not
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to accept `September 8, 1636` but reject `September 8 1636` when you erase all commas?

Comment: Im new so some it might be going over my head... what can I do to fix it?

Comment: is compiler construction or parsing or basic tokenization a prerequisite or part of "cs50"?

Comment: @kevzoz The best place to start when you're a beginner is to look at tools already available, ESPECIALLY for things like date and time formatting/conversion, string formatting, color conversion, etc. instead of trying to roll your own homebrew version.

Comment: @kevzoz I was trying to improve my answer when I noticed `results in reprompt
    expected program to reject input, but it did not` What's the difference between re-prompt and reject? In which case should the input be rejected and in which case should it be re-prompted?

Comment: As I understand it... It is supposed to accept a month spelled out if the day of the month is followed by a comma. So in the cases where its "October/1/1999" or "October 1 1999", it should reject, but my code reprompts.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz not something they've spoken about up to this point.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of rolling your own date utility, use Python's builtin `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_date():
    numeric_format = '%d%m%Y'
    long_format = '%B%d%Y'
    while True:
        # Cleans the input
        date_str = ''.join([char for char in input("Date: ") if char.isalnum()]) 
        try:
            # Converts string to date and prints it
            print(datetime.strptime(date_str, numeric_format if date_str[0].isnumeric() else long_format).date())
        except:
            pass
        
get_date()
```

Comment: this can't distinguish between "1/11/1636" and "11/1/1636"

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I quote: `implement a program that prompts the user for a date, anno Domini, in month-day-year order`. The specified format is months days years, given that specification I think the difference is pretty clear

Comment: no it's not. 1st month and 11th day, or 11th month and 1st day? your string for both is `1111636`, hence removes the difference. please look for the reasoning in someone's comment before deciding that they're wrong and you start justifying.